Moving outlook emails from one account to another
I need to create an automated task that moves emails from an outlook mailbox to another one; i need those email to be inaltered - they have to mantain the original sender and subject etc. so i can't just enable automatic forwarding. I'd need a way to keep it automated, like an auto forward but without changing the recipient
I tried the manual move keeping two emails open on the browser and it worked but i need to script it to move automatically evety mail into one specific mailbox
All mailboxes are on outlook online
Do you know any way to do it?

By "outlook online" do you mean Outlook on the web / Outlook Web Access (OWA)?

I'd expect that you can configure that on the receiving mail server, like adding an alias for the one email address that points to the other. May not work on emails already received.

@niton Outlook on the web, i don't have direct access to the server

@Robert that's a solution i did not thought. But both the mailboxes already exists and have mails in it, do you know if i loose all existing data setting the alias? Looking in ms documentation seems that i'd need to delete the existing account before creating the alias.

Normally you could VBA with desktop Outlook. Non-programming questions are better suited to Super User.
